# PHP variable not echoing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

This page is a index.html page with javascript in it.

Here is what i am using:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var balance ="<?php echo json_encode($balance, JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_APOS|JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_AMP); ?>";
      console.log(balance)
```

All the console is showing is this:

```
<?php echo json_encode($balance, JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_APOS|JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_AMP); ?>
```

I have also tried this, since I'm not sure if all those JSON tags are necessary:

```
var balance ="<?php echo json_encode($balance); ?>";
```

But it still wont work and just shows up exactly like the others in console:

```
var balance ="<?php echo "45";); ?>";
```

Edit:  I did not say it was echoing on page but in the console.   its a flash file so nothing but the flash was showing on the page. I thought this was a javascript issue i will try the solution below.  That other answer may help cause i had not thought of that.  Thanks for the solution but i believe this is not the same question

Comment: You need to name it `index.php`, or change your server configuration to run `.html` files with PHP.

Comment: adding this to the htaccess worked:
'AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm'

Answer (score 1):

If your page is .html then will probably not run php on it.  Rename to index.php and let me know.